# Node.js socket.io : TypeError Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign'

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have 2 servers with exactly the same setup. But on 1 server I ran against an error and on another server it works well.

On server 1 :

```
[root@tst socketio]# npm list socket.io
/var/socketio
└── socket.io@2.0.4 

Package nodejs-0.10.48-3.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

On server 2 :

```
[root@1 socketio]# npm list socket.io
/var/socketio
└── socket.io@2.0.4 

Package nodejs-0.10.48-3.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Script on server 1 :

```
[root@tst socketio]# node /var/socketio/socketioclient.js 1768
Time: 5/3/2018 21:10:6
ID: 1768
Start connect
S-connection
k95RAgJVnhzv4ItHABvu
S-emit event
S-disconnect
```

Script on server 2 :

```
[root@1 socketio]# node /var/socketio/socketioclient.js 1768
Time: 5/3/2018 20:59:24
ID: 1768

/var/socketio/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/xmlhttprequest-ssl/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:66
  var headers = Object.assign({}, defaultHeaders);
                       ^
TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign'
    at new XMLHttpRequest (/var/socketio/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/xmlhttprequest-ssl/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:66:24)
    at /var/socketio/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling.js:24:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/socketio/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling.js:26:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/socketio/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling-xhr.js:6:15)
```

My socketioclient.js :

```
console.log(datetime);
console.log('ID: '+ID);
var io = require('socket.io-client');
console.log('Start connect');
var sSocket = io.connect('https://11.22.33.44:1234', {
    reconnection: true,
    reconnectionDelay: 1000,
    reconnectionDelayMax : 5000,
    reconnectionAttempts: 3
});
sSocket.on('connect', function (data) {

    console.log('S-connection');
    console.log(sSocket.id);

        console.log('S-emit event');
        sSocket.emit('event', { ID: ID });
        sSocket.disconnect();

    }

    sSocket.on('serveroutput', function (data) {
        console.log('S-serveroutput: '+data);
    });

});

sSocket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
    console.log('S-disconnect');
});

sSocket.on('reconnect', function() {
    console.log('S-reconnecting');
});

sSocket.on('reconnect_failed', function (data) {
    console.log('S-reconnect failed');
});
```

I see no difference in socketio version or in nodejs version. But the outcome is different. How come ?

I have read (on this website) about needing node version >= 4. But as it works on 1 server I don't think this is the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Upgrade to the most recent [Node LTS release](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) (currently 8)

It looks like you have different versions of `xmlhttprequest-ssl`, even though the parent `socket.io` is at 2.0.4. `xmlhttprequest-ssl` version [1.5.4](https://github.com/mjwwit/node-XMLHttpRequest/releases) or newer includes the use of `Object.assign`. Versions from 1.5.2 down might work better in Node 0.10.

If you look at the paths in the stack trace, there are a number of modules other than `socket.io` involved in the error:

```
socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/xmlhttprequest-ssl
```

The `npm` command supported on Node 0.10 is non deterministic which means you can end up with two installs of the same parent module but they are made up from different child dependencies. This largely depends on when you ran the `npm install` as to what versions you get.

Recent versions of [`npm` (5.x)](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) and the [`yarn` package manager](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarn-lock/) now support lock files that fully describe an applications dependencies and will be able to create consistent installs over time.

A lot of modules have started dropping support for any Node versions prior to 4.x so this type of error is going to become more and more common for Node 0.x users.

Use the current [Long Term Support release of Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). If you require [packages for your RHEL platform](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora), Nodesource [provide rpms](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#rpm).

Comment: Should I first remove socket.io (npm uninstall socket.io) ? Should I also remove node.js completely (yum erase nodejs ) ? Before installing the new Node LTS version.

Comment: I believe the packages won't coexist, so yes you will probably need to remove the old one. If you can do the node upgrade on a test server, `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` will get everything up to date. Confirm the app all works. Then you will have a `package-lock.json` that describes a working set of dependencies that you can use where ever you need to do the install.

Comment: I have succesfully removed npm and then  nodejs. Then succesfully re-installed nodejs-8.10.0 with yum (Package 2:nodejs-8.10.0-1nodesource.x86_64 already installed and latest version
). But now I can not install npm any more. I get all sorts of conflicts, like this :
file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/sha from install of npm-1.3.6-5.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package nodejs-2:8.10.0-1nodesource.x86_64
And also :
 file /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which conflicts between attempted installs of npm-1.3.6-5.el6.noarch and nodejs-2:8.10.0-1nodesource.x86_64

Comment: Apparently npm was not removed. I could issue the following command : npm install npm@latest -g. This solved my problem with the conflicts and everything works well now.